# Apply the_title filter to post titles AND backend auto social-sharing plugin, but not nav menu

Tags: wordpress, plugins, filter, action

### The Challenge

I have been trying to write **a filter that applies (prepends a string) to (a) post titles of a certain post type and (b) to that same post type WordPress admin backend for use by an auto social sharing plugin.**

I've gotten really close.  I've achieved:
1.  prepending only to custom post_type post titles
2.  prepending to custom_post type titles AND all nav menu items
3.  prepending to ALL titles (post, page, nav menu, and backend auto-sharing plugin)

The final, 3rd attempt got me very hopeful, but yet still, no matter the function, conditional statement, or combination I use, I can't get **custom_post title AND backend social sharing plugin, but *not* nav menu items**.

### My Code - what I've tried

I've tried different conditionals, like `is_admin()` and `!is_nav_menu` with all nav menu IDs.  I've also tried comparing the ID of the post to the ID of the menu.  Finally, I've also tried adding the filter only to `loop_start` and that seems promising if combined with other statements.  I will clean up my code for your review but I leave it this way for now in hopes it helps to see what I've tried and maybe where I went wrong with any of those methods.

```
// , $id = NULL
function append_album_review_to_title( $title ) {
    global $post;
    global $dont_apply_title_filter;
    $text = 'Album Review: ';
    $prepended_title = $text . $title;
/*
    $nav_menus_obj = wp_get_nav_menus();
    $nav_menu_ids = '';
    foreach( $nav_menus_obj as $nav_menu ) {
        $nav_menu_ids .= $nav_menu->term_id . ',';
    }
    rtrim($nav_menu_ids, ',');
*/
//  if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'album_review' && in_the_loop() ){
//  if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'album_review' && $id == get_the_ID() ){
//  if ( !is_nav_menu( '32057,32058,35135,32054,32056' ) ) {
//  if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'album_review' && is_nav_menu( $id ) ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'album_review' && !$dont_apply_title_filter ) {
        //print_r( $nav_menu_ids );
        //print_r( is_nav_menu( $nav_menu_ids ) );
        return $prepended_title;
/*
    } elseif ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'album_review'  ) {
        return $title;
*/
    } else {
        return $title;
    };
}
add_filter('the_title', 'append_album_review_to_title');
//add_action('save_post', 'custom_post_type_title', 100);
/*
function set_custom_title() {
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'append_album_review_to_title', 10, 2 );
}
add_action( 'loop_start', 'set_custom_title' );
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
function append_album_review_to_title( $title, $id = NULL ) {
    if ($id) {
        if ( get_post_type( $id ) == 'album_review' ){
            return 'Album Review: ' . $title;
        } else {
            return $title;
        }
    } else {
        return 'Album Review: ' . $title;
    };
}
add_filter('the_title', 'append_album_review_to_title', 10, 2);
```

#### Explanation

First trying this:

```
function append_album_review_to_title( $title, $id ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $id ) == 'album_review' ){
        return 'Album Review: ' . $title;
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter('the_title', 'append_album_review_to_title', 10, 2);
```

I noticed that on the backend, the social sharing plugin I am using to auto-share posts would return warnings like `missing parameter 2` and `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object...`, and so it occurred to me that unlike the front end (nav menu and the loop), in the backend, apparently an `$id` is not being passed to `the_title` and so I can use this as a conditional.

Checking for `$id` will, for my purposes, tell me that if it is `true`, we are on front end, if it is `false`, then we are at backend post view.

This code accomplishes what I need (ie, modify post title in the loop, do NOT modify nav menu items, and modify `the_title` for use by a backend social sharing plugin):