# Apply the_title filter to posts but not on nav menus

Tags: wordpress

I want to apply a filter to the title of a post type, but only on its single page. So I made this function:

```
function title_filter( $title, $post_id = null ) {
    if ( ! empty( wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items( $post_id ) ) && is_singular( 'review' ) ) {
        $title = sprintf( '%1$s %2$s', $title, __( 'Review', 'stackoverflow' ) );
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'title_filter', 10, 2 );
```

But the problem is that the filter is also applied to the nav menu items that have a post of that type. I tried to exclude the filter from nav items using [`wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items/) but that doesn't seem to work. Also tried checking the post type using [`get_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) but since the menu items respond to the post type when the item is added using the post type options on the menu editor, they always match and the filter is applied anyway.

The solution given on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686999/apply-the-title-filter-to-post-titles-and-backend-auto-social-sharing-plugin-bu) didn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can check to make sure you're only filtering titles in the loop by comparing with the [`in_the_loop()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop) boolean function:

```
function mithc_title_filter( $title, $post_id = null ) {
    if( in_the_loop() && is_singular( 'review' ) ){
        $title = sprintf( '%1$s %2$s', $title, __( 'Review', 'stackoverflow' ) );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'mithc_title_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Funny enough, I just read through the codex entry for that function and the example is almost exactly what you want: "Modify Single Post Entry Titles"

Comment: Already tried `in_the_loop()` but that only helps to **exclude** everything but the loop. Meaning if I call `get_the_title( $post_id )` outside the loop, the filter is not applied. I was looking for a way to apply the filter everywhere but the nav items, but I think this will work just fine, I just have to make a loop-ish block before calling `the_title`. Thank you, @Xhynk

Comment: You can use [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) to manually apply filters to template tags, though [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) should apply `the_title` filter. Perhaps try adjusting the priority of the filter?