# how to exclude menu items in the_title filter wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having hard time excluding menu items from `the_filter` function I have to modify the post titles.

I want to modify the single post title as well as the posts in my sidebar, using `in_the_loop()` is working fine but it is also excluding my **sidebar/archive post titles, breadcrumbs etc**.

is there a way to detect menu items and exclude them? other then using `in_the_loop()`

here is my code:

```
function update_the_title( $title, $post_id ) {
    if (not menu items) {
        return $title + 'some string';
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'update_the_title');
```

Thanks

Comment: [I've been there before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282403/apply-the-title-filter-to-posts-but-not-on-nav-menus) and my "solution" was to add my own nav walker and add a filter to the title that reverts the effect of your main filter.

Comment: what is the problem again? what are the pages or widget that you want to modify the title?

Comment: i have clearly mentioned that i want to modify all the titles except menu titles

Comment: awesome, people who do not answer should at least comment the reason for down vote

Answer (score 0):

you have to try like this

**Not tested**

```
function update_the_title( $title, $post_id ) {
    $menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations(); 

    $menuID = $menuLocations['primary']; // Get the *primary* menu ID

    $primaryNav = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuID); 

    if (array_search($post_id, array_column($primaryNav, 'ID'))) {
        return $title + 'some string';
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'update_the_title', 10, 2);
```

Comment: this does the samething as `in_the_loop()`